# Django form won't validate

Tags: ajax, django, forms, validation, post

I have been spending multiple days trying to get to the bottom of this problem but I still haven't figured it out.

I'm working on a website that allows people to share or rent musical instruments to peers near them. One of the pages is "Offer Instrument", and on this page there is a form. The form has two main purposes; to allow you to search for someone near you looking for this instrument, or to post your listing to the site.

If you click "Search", the site only looks at two pieces of data, the type of instrument and the location. If you click "Post", the site looks at all the input boxes (i.e. size, age, brand, etc), and enters it in.

When you click "Search", an Ajax request is sent to the view `instrument_offering_search(request)` where it is supposed to processed and results are supposed to be returned. However the `form` object is never returning valid.

```
def instrument_offer_search(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InstrumentOfferSearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
             #always returning false
        else: 
             .....
```

When you click "Post", an Ajax request is sent to the view `instrument_offering(request)` where it is processed and added to the database. This works fine

```
def instrument_offering(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InstrumentOfferForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
             #works!
```

I've verified by using both Chrome tools and `pdb` that the Search button is definitely sending the POST data.

Why isn't the form being valid?

Comment: It is hard to speculate what might be wrong - One thing you can do is, after `if form.is_valid()`, in an `else` block - do `print form.errors` - you would know what the error message is.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'd never known of it... I will see if it helps me figure out the problem

Comment: I feel like it might be because of how you are using your model. Can you edit the question to show your Forms and models too?